# ConstraintLayout not handling clicks

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-constraintlayout

I have an empty `ConstraintLayout` (which I am using as an overlay) inside a `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

To which I have attached an event listener:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    ...
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.overlay:
                // Do something
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the overlay is clicked, `Some code here` is not getting executed. Removing `android:clickable` and `android:focusable` doesn't help. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: How about trying `myOverlay.setOnClickListener(...)` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
findViewById(R.id.overlay).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //Do something
    }
}
```

This will do the work. I don't see in your code where you actually set onclicklistener to your overlay view.

Comment: I set it here:
`public void onClick(View v) { switch(v.getId()) { case R.id.overlay: ...`.

Comment: For me, this is not working. I'm facing the same issue. @WaisKamal  Can you guide?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the logcat?

Answer (score 1):

You need do like dis

```
ConstraintLayout parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);

parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    
                }
            });
```

Comment: This works, thank you. I will accept @KirylTkach's answer because it came first.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your `oncreate` method :

```
setOnClickListener(this)
```

and do as below :

```
public class MainActivity extends Appcomatactivity implements View.OnClickListner
```

Comment: This is what I did. I will update the question.